# maximum highspeed hdmi cable length per standard

Tags: hdmi, cable

I ordered a 10m HDMI cable which was labelled "highspeed" and got a cable with the "standard" label. When asking the store, they told me, that HDMI cables, which are longer than 7.5m can't be highspeed anymore, starting early 2013.

Is it true, that a cable could lose its "highspeed" rating either because it is too long, or because the standard changed?

**EDIT**: The shop told me, that for all cables, which are longer than 10m, "highspeed" is the new standard and that they don't sell "standard" cables anymore. He insists on the fact, that the cable is a "highspeed" cable although he isn't allowed to print it on the box.

I returned the cable to get a cable from a more reliable shop...

---

I'm aware of the questions [HDMI-HDMI cable length](https://superuser.com/q/67155/257526) and [Length limit for HDMI cables](https://superuser.com/q/545796/257526), but my point is a bit different.

I'm also aware of the FAQ on [hdmi.org](http://www.hdmi.org/learningcenter/faq.aspx#44), which explicitly states, that the standard doesn't specify any length. Unfortunately, this FAQ seems a bit outdated/badly maintained.

Comment: Have you tested the cable and notice any defects, or any odd results?

Comment: I don't want to open the box, to be able to return it without a problem.

Comment: Did you contact the cable manufacturer? They may be able to explain their product and the standards it will meet.

Comment: Unfortunately, the shop and manufacturer seem to be the same...

Comment: This may have more to do with the shop's own practices than an actual standard. The "high speed" or "standard" is based on the quality of the cable, not just the length. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Cables